# fetchById could not render state in react but console.log presents state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

i have a simple react app in which i used  react-redux , axios , react-router and functional components.the component LMSCourseDetails.jsx as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useDispatch,useSelector, useStore} from 'react-redux';
import { Link,useParams,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from "../_actions/courseActions";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    display: 'flex',
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  card: {
    padding:10,
    marginTop:10,
    display: 'flex',
    flex:1,
  },
  cardAction: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: 'initial'
  },
  cardMedia: {
    width: 160,
  },
});

export default function LMSCourseDetails(props) {  
  const classes = useStyles();
  
 
     let {courseId}=useParams();
    
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.fetchById(courseId));

   }, [])

  
  const course = useSelector(state=>state.course.list)
      
     
        console.log("course type:",typeof(course)); // type is object
  return (
  <div>
<h2> this is course {course.subject}</h2> // subject does not show here why????
</div>

    
  );
}
```

here is courseReducer.js

```
import { ACTION_TYPES } from '../_constants';

const initialState = {
    list: []
}


 export const course=(state = initialState, action)=>{

    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...action.payload]
            }
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_BY_ID:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [action.payload]  // i think here is error
            }
          
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

courseApi.js to fetch data  from backend is
as follows:

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = "http://localhost:4000/api/"



export default {

    course(url = baseUrl + 'courses/') {
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
            fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id)
        }
    }
}
```

the console.log shows old state (of student) and then course state correct but does not render {course.subject} in return statement.

courseActions.js is below:

```
import courseApi from "../_services/courseApi";
import { ACTION_TYPES } from '../_constants';


const formateData = data => ({
    ...data,
   // age: parseInt(data.age ? data.age : 0)
})

export const fetchAll = () => dispatch => {
      courseApi.course().fetchAll()
        .then(response => {
            
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
export const fetchById = (id) => dispatch => {
    courseApi.course().fetchById(id)
      .then(response => {
          
          dispatch({
              type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_BY_ID,
              payload: response.data
          })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

[image: console.log screenshot here]

Comment: Did you check the redux dev tools what actions are dispatched, what their data is and what changes they cause to the state. Can you tell us what action is going wrong and what is wrong (action has missing data, state not updated correctly, ...)? It should be obvious that the first thing you look at is the dev tools but your question is missing that part.

Comment: Hi@HMR the correct action is performed and correct data is fetched .i have updated the questions to add console.log screenshot .check the screenshot kindly to help.thanks

Answer (score 0):

it started working on changing {course.subject} to {course[0].subject}